Why does this comment remain an 'answer'?
It seems that you consider humans a kind of prototype species in the universe...
This 'answer' clearly is not an answer, but a comment. It should be not stand as answer.
Why does it remain an answer?

Because no one has Flagged it yet, I suspect. Give it a go.

@ScottRowe - I already did. I suspect that because the poster has a high rep, certain people are reluctant to close it. Same with the other answer/non-answer that I asked about (and flagged). You are an engineer, I am a software developer - I don't have much time for, or interest in, philosophy - figuring out how to code something interests me far more, and it pays the bills well - better than philosophy I think, unless you are a tenured prof. (Pretty sure sure you are the same). I just like a little philosophical banter to liven it up - probably never get to 1000 rep, nor do I care.
